# video issues with amd igpu and nvidia gpu in an Aspire A715-41G laptop

Tags: 20.04, hybrid-graphics, nvidia-geforce, amd-ryzen

**update:** stability issues fixed so far by installing kernel mainline 5.6.19-050619-generic

When will kernel version 5.6 be available in the ubuntu 20.04 repositories?
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

I recently bought an acer aspire 7 laptop model A715-41G (exact model: A715-41G-R8MJ) and I had trouble setting up the video correctly.

This laptop comes with an AMD Ryzen 5 3550H processor with a discrete Nvidia Geforce gtx 1650 graphics card (AMD Ryzen 5 3550H with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx)

```
System:    Kernel: 5.4.0-42-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 9.3.0 
           parameters: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-5.4.0-42-generic root=/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root ro quiet splash 
           acpi_backlight=vendor vt.handoff=7 
           Desktop: Gnome 3.36.3 wm: gnome-shell dm: GDM3 3.34.1 Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: Acer product: Aspire A715-41G v: V1.00 serial: <filter> 
           Mobo: PK model: Azalea_PKS v: V1.00 serial: <filter> UEFI: INSYDE v: 1.00 date: 03/13/2020 
Battery:   ID-1: BAT1 charge: 12.7 Wh condition: 50.1/47.8 Wh (105%) volts: 10.6/11.2 model: LGC AP18C8K type: Li-ion 
           serial: <filter> status: Discharging 
CPU:       Topology: Quad Core model: AMD Ryzen 5 3550H with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Zen+ 
           family: 17 (23) model-id: 18 (24) stepping: 1 microcode: 8108109 L2 cache: 2048 KiB 
           flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 sse4a ssse3 svm bogomips: 33537 
           Speed: 1220 MHz min/max: 1400/2100 MHz boost: enabled Core speeds (MHz): 1: 1223 2: 1223 3: 1222 4: 1222 5: 1221 
           6: 1222 7: 1222 8: 1222 
           Vulnerabilities: Type: itlb_multihit status: Not affected 
           Type: l1tf status: Not affected 
           Type: mds status: Not affected 
           Type: meltdown status: Not affected 
           Type: spec_store_bypass mitigation: Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl and seccomp 
           Type: spectre_v1 mitigation: usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization 
           Type: spectre_v2 mitigation: Full AMD retpoline, IBPB: conditional, STIBP: disabled, RSB filling 
           Type: srbds status: Not affected 
           Type: tsx_async_abort status: Not affected
```

The Ubuntu 20.04 installation went smoothly, but when I installed the nvidia driver (sudo apt install nvidia-driver-440), **the system crashed after rebooting**.

Solution: blacklist the nouveau driver with a file in /etc/modprobe.d/ with this content

```
blacklist nouveau
options nouveau modeset = 0
```

And thanks to that I can start Ubuntu

Next problem:
The buttons to increase and decrease the brightness were reversed. Solution: I added `acpi_backlight = vendor` to /etc/default/grub file

Another problem: **high battery consumption due to the nvidia dGPU was consuming 4W all the time**.

Solution: I followed the nvidia recommendations on this page: http://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/440.100/README/dynamicpowermanagement.html about Dynamic Power Management.

I created the file 80-nvidia-pm.rules in /lib/udev/rules.d/ directory with this content

```
# Remove NVIDIA USB xHCI Host Controller devices, if present
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="pci", ATTR{vendor}=="0x10de", ATTR{class}=="0x0c0330", ATTR{remove}="1"

# Remove NVIDIA USB Type-C UCSI devices, if present
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="pci", ATTR{vendor}=="0x10de", ATTR{class}=="0x0c8000", ATTR{remove}="1"

# Remove NVIDIA Audio devices, if present
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="pci", ATTR{vendor}=="0x10de", ATTR{class}=="0x040300", ATTR{remove}="1"

# Enable runtime PM for NVIDIA VGA/3D controller devices on driver bind
ACTION=="bind", SUBSYSTEM=="pci", ATTR{vendor}=="0x10de", ATTR{class}=="0x030000", TEST=="power/control", ATTR{power/control}="auto"
ACTION=="bind", SUBSYSTEM=="pci", ATTR{vendor}=="0x10de", ATTR{class}=="0x030200", TEST=="power/control", ATTR{power/control}="auto"

# Disable runtime PM for NVIDIA VGA/3D controller devices on driver unbind
ACTION=="unbind", SUBSYSTEM=="pci", ATTR{vendor}=="0x10de", ATTR{class}=="0x030000", TEST=="power/control", ATTR{power/control}="on"
ACTION=="unbind", SUBSYSTEM=="pci", ATTR{vendor}=="0x10de", ATTR{class}=="0x030200", TEST=="power/control", ATTR{power/control}="on"
```

And I created the /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia.conf file with this content:

```
options nvidia "NVreg_DynamicPowerManagement=0x02"
```

Thanks to that, the battery performance went **from 3 hours to more than 6 hours**.

Until then, those things were all satisfactory solutions to those problems, **but I still have a problem that I can't find a good solution for. And it is the most important problem of all. I can't find a solution that allows the AMD iGPU and nvidia dGPU to work properly.**

After installing the nvidia driver and blacklisting the nouveau driver, nvidia x server settings shows a window with no content and the nvidia-smi command shows that it has no processes. I checked the /etc/X11 directory and there is no xorg.conf file

[nvidia x server empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkSgp.png)

```
$ nvidia-smi
Sun Aug  9 00:53:55 2020       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 440.100      Driver Version: 440.100      CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1650    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   38C    P0     2W /  N/A |      0MiB /  3914MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+

$ inxi -xxxG
Graphics:  Device-1: NVIDIA vendor: Acer Incorporated ALI driver: nvidia v: 440.100 bus ID: 01:00.0 chip ID: 10de:1f99 
           Device-2: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Picasso vendor: Acer Incorporated ALI driver: amdgpu v: kernel 
           bus ID: 05:00.0 chip ID: 1002:15d8 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.8 driver: modesetting unloaded: nvidia alternate: ati,fbdev,nouveau,vesa 
           compositor: gnome-shell v: 3.36.3 resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: AMD RAVEN (DRM 3.35.0 5.4.0-42-generic LLVM 10.0.0) v: 4.6 Mesa 20.0.8 direct render: Yes 

$ xrandr --listproviders
Providers: number : 1
Provider 0: id: 0x45 cap: 0x9, Source Output, Sink Offload crtcs: 4 outputs: 2 associated providers: 0 name:modesetting
```

After searching the web, I find this model xorg.conf file.

```
Section "ServerLayout"
        Identifier "layout"
        Option "AllowNVIDIAGPUScreens"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        Identifier "AMDGPU"
        Driver "amdgpu"
        Option "TearFree" "true"
EndSection

Section "OutputClass"
        Identifier "iGPU"
        MatchDriver "amdgpu"
        Driver "modesetting"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        Identifier "nvidia"
        Driver "nvidia"
EndSection

Section "OutputClass"
        Identifier "nvidia"
        MatchDriver "nvidia-drm"
        Driver "nvidia"
        Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration"
        ModulePath "/usr/lib/nvidia/xorg"
        ModulePath "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
EndSection
```

I don't like copying and pasting anything, but this got it working and now nvidia x server settings shows content and nvidia-smi shows processes.

[nvidia x server now shows somethig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXtGM.png)

```
$nvidia-smi

Sun Aug  9 00:43:55 2020       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 440.100      Driver Version: 440.100      CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1650    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   36C    P8     1W /  N/A |     49MiB /  3914MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1249      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            14MiB |
|    0      1897      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            34MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+

$inxi -xxxG
Graphics:  Device-1: NVIDIA vendor: Acer Incorporated ALI driver: nvidia v: 440.100 bus ID: 01:00.0 chip ID: 10de:1f99 
           Device-2: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Picasso vendor: Acer Incorporated ALI driver: amdgpu v: kernel 
           bus ID: 05:00.0 chip ID: 1002:15d8 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.8 driver: modesetting,nvidia alternate: amdgpu,ati,fbdev,nouveau,vesa 
           compositor: gnome-shell v: 3.36.3 resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: AMD RAVEN (DRM 3.35.0 5.4.0-42-generic LLVM 10.0.0) v: 4.6 Mesa 20.0.8 direct render: Yes 

$xrandr --listproviders
Providers: number : 2
Provider 0: id: 0x45 cap: 0x9, Source Output, Sink Offload crtcs: 4 outputs: 2 associated providers: 0 name:modesetting
Provider 1: id: 0x231 cap: 0x0 crtcs: 0 outputs: 0 associated providers: 0 name:NVIDIA-G0
```

The downside of this solution is that **it leaves the system unstable**. On the login screen sometimes it does not show the pointer, and although when I restart it takes a little longer, **when I turn on the laptop after being a few minutes off, the system shows a black screen**, I don't even have ssh access and I just get it to work after one or two attempts to turn off completely and turn on again.

**dmesg showing that something went very wrong**

```
[   29.654785] kernel: [drm:amdgpu_job_timedout [amdgpu]] *ERROR* ring gfx timeout, signaled seq=1, emitted seq=3
[   29.654918] kernel: [drm:amdgpu_job_timedout [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Process information: process Xorg pid 1249 thread Xorg:cs0 pid 1344
[   29.654926] kernel: amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: GPU reset begin!
[   30.777283] kernel: amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: GPU reset succeeded, trying to resume
[   30.777892] kernel: [drm] PCIE GART of 1024M enabled (table at 0x000000F400900000).
[   30.778481] kernel: [drm] PSP is resuming...
[   30.798357] kernel: [drm] reserve 0x400000 from 0xf47f800000 for PSP TMR
[   30.809000] kernel: [drm] psp command failed and response status is (0x7)
[   31.479027] kernel: [drm] VCN decode and encode initialized successfully(under DPG Mode).
[   31.479037] kernel: amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: ring gfx uses VM inv eng 0 on hub 0
[   31.479040] kernel: amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: ring comp_1.0.0 uses VM inv eng 1 on hub 0
[   31.479043] kernel: amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: ring comp_1.1.0 uses VM inv eng 4 on hub 0
[   31.479045] kernel: amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: ring comp_1.2.0 uses VM inv eng 5 on hub 0
[   31.479048] kernel: amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: ring comp_1.3.0 uses VM inv eng 6 on hub 0
[   31.479050] kernel: amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: ring comp_1.0.1 uses VM inv eng 7 on hub 0
[   31.479052] kernel: amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: ring comp_1.1.1 uses VM inv eng 8 on hub 0
[   31.479054] kernel: amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: ring comp_1.2.1 uses VM inv eng 9 on hub 0
[   31.479057] kernel: amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: ring comp_1.3.1 uses VM inv eng 10 on hub 0
[   31.479059] kernel: amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: ring kiq_2.1.0 uses VM inv eng 11 on hub 0
[   31.479062] kernel: amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: ring sdma0 uses VM inv eng 0 on hub 1
[   31.479064] kernel: amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: ring vcn_dec uses VM inv eng 1 on hub 1
[   31.479065] kernel: amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: ring vcn_enc0 uses VM inv eng 4 on hub 1
[   31.479068] kernel: amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: ring vcn_enc1 uses VM inv eng 5 on hub 1
[   31.479070] kernel: amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: ring vcn_jpeg uses VM inv eng 6 on hub 1
[   31.490635] kernel: [drm] recover vram bo from shadow start
[   31.490636] kernel: [drm] recover vram bo from shadow done
[   31.490637] kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[   31.490675] kernel: ------------[ cut here ]------------
[   31.490681] kernel: WARNING: CPU: 3 PID: 74 at include/linux/dma-fence.h:533 drm_sched_resubmit_jobs+0x152/0x160 [gpu_sched]
[   31.490682] kernel: Modules linked in: ccm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher vboxnetadp(OE) vboxnetflt(OE) af_alg vboxdrv(OE) bnep binfmt_misc nls_iso8859_1 snd_soc_dmic snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_acp3x_pdm_dma acp3x_rn snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_soc_core snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_hda_codec uvcvideo joydev snd_hda_core snd_hwdep videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops edac_mce_amd btusb btrtl videobuf2_v4l2 btbcm snd_pcm videobuf2_common kvm_amd btintel bluetooth snd_seq_midi ccp videodev snd_seq_midi_event iwlmvm ecdh_generic kvm ecc snd_rawmidi mc mac80211 snd_seq snd_seq_device libarc4 snd_timer hid_multitouch input_leds serio_raw acer_wmi wmi_bmof sparse_keymap k10temp iwlwifi snd snd_rn_pci_acp3x snd_pci_acp3x cfg80211 soundcore mac_hid acer_wireless nvidia_uvm(OE) sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 dm_crypt nvidia_drm(POE) nvidia_modeset(POE) nvidia(POE) amdgpu crct10dif_pclmul
[   31.490707] kernel:  crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel amd_iommu_v2 hid_generic aesni_intel gpu_sched i2c_algo_bit ttm crypto_simd cryptd drm_kms_helper glue_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect nvme sysimgblt fb_sys_fops r8169 ahci ipmi_devintf i2c_piix4 drm libahci nvme_core realtek ipmi_msghandler i2c_hid video hid wmi
[   31.490720] kernel: CPU: 3 PID: 74 Comm: kworker/3:1 Tainted: P           OE     5.4.0-42-generic #46-Ubuntu
[   31.490721] kernel: Hardware name: Acer Aspire A715-41G/Azalea_PKS, BIOS V1.00 03/13/2020
[   31.490724] kernel: Workqueue: events drm_sched_job_timedout [gpu_sched]
[   31.490727] kernel: RIP: 0010:drm_sched_resubmit_jobs+0x152/0x160 [gpu_sched]
[   31.490729] kernel: Code: 41 5c 41 5d 41 5e 41 5f 5d c3 49 8b 46 10 31 c9 48 c7 80 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 49 8b 7f 70 31 c0 83 e7 01 74 04 0f 0b eb bf <0f> 0b eb c7 0f 0b eb 8b 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 0f 1f 44 00 00 55 48 89
[   31.490730] kernel: RSP: 0018:ffffab6b403d3d28 EFLAGS: 00010246
[   31.490731] kernel: RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 0000000000000001 RCX: 0000000000000000
[   31.490732] kernel: RDX: ffffa069d4b4a280 RSI: ffffa069e3dcb1f8 RDI: 0000000000000000
[   31.490733] kernel: RBP: ffffab6b403d3d60 R08: 000000000000050b R09: 0000000000000004
[   31.490733] kernel: R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000001 R12: ffffa069d1b87ad8
[   31.490734] kernel: R13: ffffa069d1b87980 R14: ffffa069e3dcb000 R15: ffffa069d4b4a240
[   31.490735] kernel: FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffffa069e88c0000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[   31.490736] kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[   31.490737] kernel: CR2: 00007f4aeb7fdb38 CR3: 00000001e043a000 CR4: 00000000003406e0
[   31.490738] kernel: Call Trace:
[   31.490827] kernel:  amdgpu_device_gpu_recover+0x6cd/0x95a [amdgpu]
[   31.490907] kernel:  amdgpu_job_timedout+0x103/0x130 [amdgpu]
[   31.490909] kernel:  drm_sched_job_timedout+0x44/0x90 [gpu_sched]
[   31.490914] kernel:  process_one_work+0x1eb/0x3b0
[   31.490916] kernel:  worker_thread+0x4d/0x400
[   31.490919] kernel:  kthread+0x104/0x140
[   31.490921] kernel:  ? process_one_work+0x3b0/0x3b0
[   31.490922] kernel:  ? kthread_park+0x90/0x90
[   31.490927] kernel:  ret_from_fork+0x22/0x40
[   31.490928] kernel: ---[ end trace 3f6c6090efb5a251 ]---
[   31.490960] kernel: amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: GPU reset(2) succeeded!
```

I also verified that the system is also unstable with this content in the xorg.conf file:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
      Identifier "layout"
      Option "AllowNVIDIAGPUScreens"
EndSection
```

**I ran out of ideas, does anyone know how is the correct way to configure these hybrid graphics systems AMD + Nvidia?**

If you got here, thank you for taking the time to read all this, I tried to give all the information that I could gather.

If you notice something strange in the writing, please excuse me, English is not my mother tongue and I do not usually write often

**EDIT:** I was able to get access via ssh. This is the information that I was able to collect [pastebin with dmesg](https://pastebin.com/t5ZsaABm)

The only way to reboot was with `echo b /proc/sysrq-trigger` because neither `sudo reboot` nor `systemctl reboot` worked, everything was slow and blocked

As I said before, **this crash happens when turning on the laptop**, it doesn't happen when rebooting

Answer (score 0):

I have the same laptop and with no real time to chose what to do I just installed Pop!_OS and it works perfectly and I can choose to use only integrated, dedicated or hybrid gpu modes.